# How to combine multiple keydown event in one function using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have created two text boxes and I have restricted the user not to allow text with help of keydown events in master page.

```
<label>Amount</label>
<div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<label>Amount</label>
<div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountvalue"  class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

```
if ("input[id$='txtAmount']")
  $(this).keydown(function (event) {
    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || 
      (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || 
      (event.keyCode == 8) || (event.keyCode == 9) || (event.keyCode == 12) || 
      (event.keyCode == 27) || (event.keyCode == 37) || (event.keyCode == 9) || 
      (event.keyCode == 39) || (event.keyCode == 46) || (event.keyCode == 190) || 
      (event.keyCode == 110)) { 
      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
});

if ("input[id$='txtAmountvalue']")
  $(this).keydown(function (event) {
    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || 
      (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || 
      (event.keyCode == 8) || (event.keyCode == 9) || (event.keyCode == 12) || 
      (event.keyCode == 27) || (event.keyCode == 37) || (event.keyCode == 9) || 
      (event.keyCode == 39) || (event.keyCode == 46) || (event.keyCode == 190) ||   
      (event.keyCode == 110)) { 
      return true;
    } else { 
      return false; 
    }
});
```

I have created two keydown events but the given values are same for both two text boxes.So my question is how to combine both the keydown events in one function?

Comment: Your syntax looks very weird given the `if` statement using a string literal (which will always equate to `true`), the keydown attaching to an undefined `this` scope, and the massive `if` statement which can be simplified. I'm surprised this works at all. Either way, to join two selectors in a jQuery object use a comma: `$('input[id$="txtAmount"], input[id$="txtAmountvalue"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery contain selector with (id*='yourid') for both you inpurt knowing they statrts by `txtAmount` text in their ID's
as beow snippet :

```js
$("input[id*='txtAmount']").keydown(function(event) {
  if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||
    (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) ||
    (event.keyCode == 8) || (event.keyCode == 9) || (event.keyCode == 12) ||
    (event.keyCode == 27) || (event.keyCode == 37) || (event.keyCode == 9) ||
    (event.keyCode == 39) || (event.keyCode == 46) || (event.keyCode == 190) ||
    (event.keyCode == 110)) {
    console.log("true");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("false");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Amount</label>
<div>
  <input id="txtAmount" class="form-control" runat="server" />
</div>
<label>Amount</label>
<div>
  <input id="txtAmountvalue" class="form-control" runat="server" />
</div>
```